# Perl Script Is Removing Spaces In Match

Tags: perl

I have script that works well but the problem I am having is that it is combining all the words in the match and removing the spacing. If anyone can help tell me what extra I have or I am missing to prevent the script from combining the words in the match.

```
use strict;

my $find = '^M0|MT';
my $match = 0;

open (NEW, ">", "Output.txt" ) or die "could not open:$!";
open (FILE, "<", "File.txt") or die "could not open:$!";

while (<FILE>) {
    chomp;

if ($match){
    $match = 0;
    s/\s+//g;
    print NEW "$_\n";
}

if (/$find/){
    $match = 1;
    print NEW "$_"
}
}
close (FILE);
close (NEW);
```

File Example

```
          U# mul acc       UNIT # HAS MULTIPLE ACCOUNTS          FAIL
```

Output Example (What is currently happening with my script)

```
          U#mulaccUNIT#HASMULTIPLEACCOUNTSFAIL
```

Comment: What are you trying to do with the line `s/\s+//g;`?

Comment: The code you provided does not produce the output you claim it does for the sample input. It produces empty file. The reason is that you are searching for `^M0|MT`, which is not present in the sample File.txt. Changing sample file to match that regex, still does not produce the output you claim. Instead, the original line is stored into the Output.txt file (with the newline missing).

Comment: due to private information i removed the first line it looks for, sorry about that, i should of added a generic line.  On my (/$find/) how would I set the print NEW to state, only print NEW if the characters match the first to columns of the line? @bart

Comment: @PhoenixJay That's a totally different question, it would be better to make a new post for that.

Comment: Sorry about that, I found out what i was missing.. () around my find ^M0|MT

Comment: Note that that means "begins with M0 or contains MT".  If you want "begins with M0 or MT" you need to change it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @ThisSuitIsBlackNot already pointed to:

The line

```
s/\s+//g;
```

Is eating your spaces. It states: replace a sequence of one or more spaces by nothing and repeat for the complete input string.

Looks like you intended to say:

```
s/\s+/ /g;
```

so, just replacing the sequences of  spaces by a single space.

Comment: Thank you! @ThisSuitIsBlackNot , I knew it was something simple I just couldn't figure it out for the life of me. I am very new to PERL so I have been slowly learning the language as I go.